# Error "variable is not defined", but the variable can be called in the console

Tags: python, spyder

I use python on Spyder. My script uses a variable called imgs. I have the following error : name 'imgs' is not defined. But when I try to call imgs in the console, it works, I don't have any error.

Then, I tried to write x=2 in the console of Spyder. Then, I executed a script on spyder (white juste 1 line : print(x)), and I still have the same error : name 'x' is not defined.

I never had this error before

[image]

Comment: It sounds like the execution of scripts happens within its own session, separate from any interactive shell you are working in.

Comment: Variables in your console session aren't seen in the scripts you run. Your problem is in `test.py` and that's what we should see and debug. Note, if `test.py` is big, make a smaller one demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Joshua :  Yes, do you know how to change that ?
tdelaney : test.py only has one line : print(imgs)

Answer (score 0):

***That's because the console can remember recent variables defined in a script, but the script cannot once their gone.***

Let me put it this way:

You run a script that imports the math module. Then you go to your script and delete the 'import math' statement.

You will still be able to use the math module without importing it again in the console, as long as you haven't closed the console after you ran the original working script.

Comment: I tried, it works as you say. But today I had to reinstal python, and I'm 100% confident that it didn't work like that before on my computer. Before, I was able to call a new variable in the console for example, and when I tried to execute a script using this variable, it worked ! Same thing for a package : I was able to import math in the console, and use a math fonction in a script without writing 'import math' in the script

Answer (score 0):

You should try running in consoles's namespace
[Run Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIZDq.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).